# Gem Vs Plugin Vs Engine in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What is the difference between Gem package, plugin, and Engine in Ruby on Rails?

I think we use the plugin before Rails3.2 and after rails3.2 is released we are using the gem package as a plugin but how can we use the engine in ROR?

Answer (score 21):

Plugins as you knew them from Rails 2 (i.e. plugins under the `vendor/plugins` folder) were deprecated for Rails 3.2; support for it was completely removed in Rails 4.  Now, there's a concept of a ["gamified plugin"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#setup) where the plugins are essentially built as gems and can be shared across different Rails applications.

But to answer your question about gems vs plugins, check out this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5521244/631834). Long story short, `plugins` from the Rails 2 universe is an ***extension*** of the rails application, whereas a gem is a packaged ruby application.

As for Rails engines, I've found this to be [a pretty easy and intuitive definition](http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2014/02/11/rails-4-engines/) of a Rails engine:

> Rails Engines is basically a whole Rails app that lives in the container of another one. Put another way, as the docs note: an app itself is basically just an engine at the root level. Over the years, we’ve seen sen engines as parts of gems such as devise or rails_admin. These examples show the power of engines by providing a large set of relatively self-contained functionality “mounted” into an app.

And since both rails engines and plugins are types of ruby applications, they can all technically be packaged and used as a gem (usually).

Answer (score 19):

There are no more **plugins** since Rails 4. [Rails 4.0 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#railties-deprecations):

> Rails::Plugin has gone. Instead of adding plugins to vendor/plugins
> use gems or bundlers with path or git dependencies.

Any **engine** can be contained in a gem. Gem is just an alias to a 'library'.

---

**Best way to see what their difference is is by generating three of them and looking through their directory structure**:

`bundle gem a_gem`, used for non-rails-specific functionality.

`rails plugin new b_railtie`, used for rails extensions that don't require a full application-like setup. but, since it's still a rails-specific setup (you get your Rails dummy app in `/test` eg), you are probably going to use **railtie** in it. **railtie** is a class that inherits from `Rails::Railtie`, and gives you the comfortable DSL to hook up your code into Rails. eg, if you want some action performed `:before` some Rails app initialization step, you can use `initializer` Railtie class_method. [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/523bd46c768226893f23889079a7aa9c73b57d68/lib/paperclip/railtie.rb)

`rails plugin new c_engine --full`, use for rails extensions that will be full-fledged app themselves, mounted into your app. will give you `/app` dir and `Engine` subclass besides basic non-`--full` setup.

`rails plugin new c_engine --mountable`, same as `--full`, but will create namespaces, ready to be mounted into your app engine. [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree)

And here is a pretty good link: http://hawkins.io/2012/03/defining_plugins_gems_railties_and_engines.

Answer (score 1):

Engines are very related to plugins. Engines can be plugins and plugins can be engines. All of them can be created using `rails plugin` generator with 2 different options `--full` or `--mountable`.

I think the main difference here is between Engines and Gems.

**Gems** is just a bit of code providing a set of functionalities to anyone who integrates it into its code.

It contains:

- Gemspec
- Lib folder

Can be packaged and pushed to RubyGems servers

**Engines** are actually gems. All engines can be gems (if packaged) but not all gems are engines.

We can say it with a different word, Engines is a ***Ruby on Rails*** feature, that can contain Rails-specific entities: models, controllers, views, and migrations.

It needs to be integrated inside ***Rails*** application and can't run on its own.

Very good and quick read [Artricle](https://devblast.com/b/gems-vs-engines-know-the-difference)