# Install gem manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to install a gem mannually.
I have downloaded the content of the git repo, modified the gemfile.lock (delete rails version depedencie in order to use the gem in my superior version of Rails). 
But where do I put the folder and how do I add this folder to my gem list?

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/mustardseeddatabase/doccex)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118472/gem-vs-plugin-vs-engine-in-ruby-on-rails Check the difference between gem and engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Gemfile` you just put 
`gem 'gem_name', :path => "path_to_gem"`